# Proof problem of quotient rule

Tags: calculus

I proved that:
$$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{f(x + h)}{g(x + h)} - \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{f(x + h) \times g(x) - f(x) \times g(x + h)}{g(x) \times g(x + h)}}{h} = lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + h) \times g(x) - f(x) \times g(x + h)}{g(x + h) \times g(x) \times h}$$
g(x + h) becomes g(x)
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + h) \times g(x) - f(x) \times g(x)}{{g(x)}^2 \times h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x) \times \left( f(x + h) - f(x) \right)}{{g(x)}^2 \times h} = \frac{f'(x)}{g(x)}$$
There are other proofs that $\frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right) = \frac{f'(x) \times g(x) - g'(x) \times f(x)}{{g(x)}^2}$ but I proved that $\frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right) = \frac{f'(x)}{g(x)} \neq \frac{f'(x) \times g(x) - g'(x) \times f(x)}{{g(x)}^2}$
What wrong with this?

Comment: Yikes, gotta be careful with the formatting.

Comment: You have to be careful when replacing $g(x+h)$ by $g(x)$ in the numerator... That is where your proof breaks down. You might also want to make some noise about $g$ being non-zero on some neighbourhood.

Comment: Why $f(x+h)$ does not become $f(x) $

Comment: You cannot just replace g(x+h) with g(x) however you like. You are supposed to use the linearization $g(x+h) \sim g'(x)h +g(x)$

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac{f(x+h)}{g(x+h)}-\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)g(x)-f(x)g(x+h)}{g(x+h)g(x)h}.$$

**Hint:**  The key step is

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)g(x)\color{blue}{-f(x)g(x)+f(x)g(x)}-f(x)g(x+h)}{g(x+h)g(x)h}$$

---

Edit:  taking this further, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)g(x)-f(x)g(x)}{g(x+h)g(x)h}+\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x)g(x)-f(x)g(x+h)}{g(x+h)g(x)h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{g(x+h)h}-\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\lim_{h\to0}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{g(x+h)h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac1{g(x+h)}\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\lim_{h\to0}\frac1{g(x+h)}\lim_{h\to0}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}\\
&=\frac1{g(x)}f'(x)-\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\frac1{g(x)}g'(x)\\
&=\frac{f'(x)g(x)-g'(x)f(x)}{[g(x)]^2}
\end{align}
as desired (obviously with the assumption that $g(x)\neq0$).

Comment: I mustn't use limit properties except if limits are found.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanKhairi I'm not sure I understand your comment at all

Comment: I mean $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + h) \times g(x) - f(x) \times g(x + h)}{g(x + h) \times g(x) \times h} \neq \frac{f(x + h) \times g(x) - f(x) \times (\lim_{h \to 0} g(x + h))}{g(x + h) \times g(x) \times h}$

Comment: @AbdulrahmanKhairi I'm still not following.  Is this something that I have written?